# Attribute-based helper with lambda expressions for data-bind for integrating knockout.js with MVC4/5 + Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I just tried `KnockoutMvc` and while I admire the creator's effort, I find it is a little too heavy-handed to be useful in general. However I like to minimize the amount of JavaScript in my Razor views, especially boilerplate JavaScript (like binding my serverside view models to clientside view models).

Is there any library out there that allows you to use syntax like:

`<span data-bind="@Html.DataBindFor(m => m.MyProperty)"></span>`

Alternatively, if I were to go about trying to write my own, approximately what (very general) components would I need to make the library useful? I am assuming at a minimum I would need:

1. A custom set of attributes for defining how each model / property / method would be bound
2. An extension method for use in Razor views to use reflection to find out the attribute values
3. An extension method for use in Razor to generate the (minimal?) JavaScript to bind the client view model to the Razor Model and functions to call the server while necessary

Finally, assuming this library doesn't exist, is there a good reason it doesn't exist? IE is there no way to really work this problem in generality such that a helper method is, uh, helpful?

The reason I ask is because the library `Lib.Web.Mvc.JqGrid` has helped me create interactive tables really quickly with absolutely minimal amounts of JavaScript (just enough to format columns and such) and I wonder why the same does not exist for `knockout.js`.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin? It helps you get rid of manually converting your server-side models to the client-side view models.

Comment: It is included in my view but I am not using it - would I use `Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` to serialize the `ViewModel` ? If so, I guess the only JavaScript to write would be the methods that would call back to the server...

Comment: I elaborated a bit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get rid of manually translating the server-side models to the client-side view models, you can employ the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin which is then used like this:

```
@model ViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModel(initData) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(initData, {}, self);

        // Add custom view model logic
        ...

        // Logic for persisting the current state of the model back to the server
        self.Save = function() {                
            $.ajax('/model-uri', {
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: ko.toJSON(self),
              success: function (response) {
                  alert('Success!');
              },
              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
              }              
         });
    };

    var initialData = @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
    var model = new ViewModel(initialData);
    ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
```

Note that we're serializing the server-provided view model to a JavaScript object and then making its properties observable using the [`ko.mapping`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Knockout.Mapping) plugin which saves us duplicating the view model definition on the client side. We also employ the `ko.toJSON` utility function when sending the updated model back to the server.

The mapping procedure can be customized to ignore certain properties:

```
var mapping = {
    'ignore': ["propertyToIgnore", "alsoIgnoreThis"]
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
```

There are more mapping customizations available, described on the [plugin page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: Two questions - 1) In your answer, where is the handler for `save`'s completion? How does the client know what to do once the model has posted and gotten a response? 2) Suppose my ViewModel is very large, and/or my user has a slow Internet connection. Is there a way to include only certain fields in my model?

Comment: 1) I ommited the handler for brevity, added it now. 2) Added to the answer.

Comment: One more question on the handler: do I need to do anything with the response? Or is that somehow magically taken care of by the fact that the members of the `ViewModel` are observable?

Comment: I would say the best practice is to let the user know you are trying to save the data (e.g. by displaying "Saving..." before you issue the AJAX request) and let him know that it's finished via the `success` callback (by hiding the message, for instance). You definitely have to handle the server errors (via the `error` callback) since the user has to know that the data could not be persisted. Displaying a clearly visible error message would be appropriate.